# Spring Security Role-Based Authorization Issue: 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: java, spring, authentication, jwt, user-roles

**Problem:**

I am trying to create a Spring-based web server with role-based authentication, but I consistently receive a 403 Forbidden error. I have implemented a custom `UserDetails` class, and I suspect there might be an issue with my configuration.

**Code:**

Custom `UserDetails`:

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(r -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + r.getName())).toList();
    }

    // ... other UserDetails methods
}
```

`SecurityFilterChain` implementation:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/secret/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
        .addFilterBefore(authorizeFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .build();
}
```

I've implemented a custom `UserDetails` class and configured Spring Security for role-based authentication. However, I keep encountering a 403 Forbidden error, even though I believe the roles are correctly assigned. I've tried using both `hasRole` and `hasAuthority`, but the issue persists. What am I missing in my configuration?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resource servers with JWTs, authorities are set by the authentication converter.

The default authentication converter is `JwtAuthenticarionConverter`, which delegates authorities convertion to a configurable authorities converter (the default uses the entries in `scope` claim adding `SCOPE_` prefix).

You can provide a `JwtAuthenticationConverter` configured with another authorities converter (one using another claim as source for authorities), or switch to a completely different `Converter<Jwt,? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>` by using `http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2-> oauth2.jwt(Jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(...))`

You might also consider [this additional starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) I maintain which uses an authorities converter configurable with just application properties (unless you provide your own authorities or authentication converter in your conf)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have gotten rid of the `"ROLE_"` prefix from `CustomUserDetails`, changed my claims name to `scope`, and added the `"SCOPE_"` prefix to the `hasAuthority(...)` function. Now it's working.

Comment: Be aware that most OpenID Providers use `scope` claim for scopes other (private) claim(s) for roles: by default, Keycloak uses `realm_access.roles` and `resource_access.{client-id}.roles`, Amazon Cognito uses `cognito:groups`, Auth0 whatever you configure it to use, etc. So you'd better check your provider doc. Also, your `UserDetails` implementation is probably never called on a resource server with JWT decoder (in which case you should remove it).

Comment: I implemented a custom method for `JwtAuthenticationConverter` setup. Now, it no longer uses the `scope` claims, but the authorization is still working as it intend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the TRACE log for spring and find out where the question happers. This suggestion may not help you directly, but it did help us find the reason why the API returned 403 when we migrated to Springboot3.0